# php include error when using ftps (ftp over ssl / tls )

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, include

i try to include a file from a remote server. When i use normal ftp everything works well. when i try to use ftps ...

```
<?php
  $erg = include("ftps://user:pw@ftp.doamin.de/files/toinclude.php");
?>
```

i got an error:

```
Warning: include(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /var/www/html/includetest.php on line 10
Warning: include(ftps://...@ftp.domain.de/files/toinclude.php): failed to open stream: Unable to activate SSL mode in /var/www/html/includetest.php on line 10
```

the ftpserver is able to work in "ftp over tls" mode when i use filezilla to connect.
on the webserver openssl is activated in this version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

i already searched the web and this site for quite a while but without any sucess.

lg grischan